# Is the following set stratified (and why not) in New Foundations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification, first-order-logic

notation:

$Id=\{\langle x,y\rangle : x=y\}$ (identity relation)

$X[y]$ (image of an element y under a relation X)

the set I am asking for is:

$Z=\{\langle x,y\rangle : \neg \exists k\; y \in k \wedge \langle y,k\rangle \in x\}[Id]$

in words:

it is an image of the element (which is a relation) $Id$ under $\{\langle x,y\rangle : \neg \exists k\; y \in k \wedge \langle y,k\rangle \in x\}$

Comment: $Z$ is just the Russell set, $\{x: x\not\in x\}$, right?

Comment: Yes. But it is constructed with seemingly stratified sets. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I know - just making sure I was keeping up. I'm also interested to see why this way of defining the Russell set isn't stratified.

Comment: How do you stratify $\langle y,k \rangle$ ? If it is $\{ \{y \} \{ y, k \} \}$ and we have $y \in \{y \}$ and $y \in k$ ... I'm not able "to see" it.

Comment: Thanks. That's probably it. level(x)=level(y) (because <x,y>). But level(y) < level(x) because $<y,k> \in x$. Additionally level(k)=level(y)+1 but level(y)=level(k) because of <y,k>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition for *stratification* for a formula $\Phi$ in Quine's [*New Foundation*](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quine-nf/) :

> > requires that there should be a function $\sigma$ (a “stratification”) from the bound variables in $\Phi$ to an initial segment of the natural numbers such that if ‘$u \in v$’ is a subformula of $\Phi$ then $\sigma(v) = \sigma (u) + 1$ and if ‘$u = v$’ is a subformula of $\Phi$ then $\sigma (v) = \sigma(u)$.

In your proposal, you are using $\langle y, k \rangle$, that is $\{ \{ y \} \{ y, k \} \}$; because of $y \in \{ y \}$ we need $\sigma(y) = n$ and $\sigma(\{ y \}) = n+1$, and also $\sigma(\{ y, k \}) = n+1$.

We have also $y \in k$, so that $\sigma(k) = n+1$.

But $k \in \{ y, k \}$ and this conflicts with the above assignements.

According to the *SEP* entry :

> to fully understand stratification [...] It's harder when one has formulæ no longer in primitive notation, and the reader encounters these difficulties very early on, since the ordered pair is not a set-theoretic notion. How does one determine whether or not a formula is stratified when it contains subformulæ like $ƒ(x) = y$? The answer is that of course one has to fix an implementation of ordered pair and stick to it. Does that mean that — for formulæ involving ordered pairs — whether or not the given formula is stratified depends on how one implements ordered pairs? The answer is ‘yes' but the situation is not as grave as this suggests. There are various standard definitions of ordered pair [see [pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Quine-Rosser_definition)], and they are all legitimate in $NF$, and all satisfactory in the sense that they are “level” or homogeneous. All of them make the formula $\langle x, y \rangle = z$ stratified and give the variables $x$ and $y$ the same type; $z$ takes a higher type in most cases (never lower). How much higher depends on the version of ordered pair being used, but there are very few formulæ that come out stratified on one version of ordered pair but unstratified on another, and they are all pathological in ways reminiscent of the paradoxes.

Thus, in every case we have problems with the formula $y \in k \land \langle y, k \rangle \in x$.

Comment: However, there is a level pairing function in NF that avoids this problem.

Comment: @ZhenLin - but *if* the OP's formula is a "correct" proxy for $\lnot x \in x$, I presume that it **must** be not stratifiable, because, in general, $x_n \in y_n$ is not well-formed...

Comment: Well, _something_ has to be non-stratified. But having a [type-level pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Quine-Rosser_definition) is not a problem.

Comment: @ZhenLin - Ok; we have the fact that $y, k \in \{ \{ y \} \{ y, k \} \}$ causes no harm: the *pairing function* allows us to have the correct stratification. My answer (assuming that is the correct one) take into account this fact **and**, in addition, the fact that the OP's formula has $y \in k$; and now, I presume, we cannot consistently stratify the *conjunction* of both.

Comment: @ZhenLin - You comment says that in Quine's *NF* not necessarily $\langle y, k \rangle$ must be defined in the Wieenr-Kuratowski way ? If so, my above comment does not apply. But still, also with *NF* definition, I assume that $y \in \langle y, k \rangle$, and this conflicts with $y \in k$ ... What's your opinion ?

Comment: No, we don't have $y \in \langle y, k \rangle$ in general. The type-level pairing function has the property that $\langle y, k \rangle$ has the same level as $y$ and $k$. This is a more direct path to a contradiction.

Comment: @ZhenLin - if I've understood well Quine-Rosser definition, we have that : $A, B \subset (A, B)$. But this means that $(A,B)$ has level $+1$ compared to the level of $A$ and $B$; this is why the formula **is** stratifiable ... Is it right ?

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect. $x \subseteq x$, that doesn't mean $x$ has level one higher than itself!

Comment: @ZhenLin - right, Thanks !